# Webdriver 3.0.0-beta3 fails to interact with browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am working on selenium automation. Today I updated my pom file to have latest dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
```

After this none of my tests are running on the browsers. Say firefox is on version 48 and it opens up but the webdriver is not interacting with the browser. The error log I get is :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
,"syncGUID":"Ei_LbuNEIU60","location":"app-global","version":"48.0.2","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0",
 "updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL ":null,"icons": {"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,
"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1475694945987,"updateDate":1475694945987,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":21905,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0.2","maxVersion":"48.0.2"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
```

This is the new error I am getting this morning after changing the jre and jdk to 32 bit on 64bit machine

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
,"syncGUID":"qLUZlH20Y8gq","location":"app-global","version":"48.0.2","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1475694945987,"updateDate":1475694945987,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":21905,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0.2","maxVersion":"48.0.2"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1475767803924   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the incompatibility issue between `Selenium3` and `Mozilla Firefox` version.

Actually `Selenium3` supports executable [`geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to launch [`Mozilla Firefox >= v47`](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) just like other drivers.

[To work around you need to download latest executable geckodriver and extract downloaded zip into your system at any location](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and set `Syetem` property with `webdriver.gecko.driver` to point with download executable geckodriver location as below :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: I did add gecko driver earlier and also added desired capabilities capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true); My colleague asked me to change jre to 32 bit which is working fine on his machine. I did it and now I am getting different error.

Comment: For chrome, it launches the browser, passes the url and then it doesn't interact with the elements. It fails

Comment: Ok, could you share your tried code that how are you initialising webdriver as well, that's why I could examine what is the issue??